# I cannot find my error and it repeats forever

Tags: python, infinite-loop

Below while-loop is meant to repeat forever (thus `i=0` never modified inside the loop). The loop has a `checkpoint` so every read line continues where it left off.

But the checkpoint is not working, any way to fix that? Okay, I am not modifying the i var (which is a big suggestion) unless it is done, so it repeats, resumes checkpoint, and writes data, repeat. BUT what I am trying to say is that the checkpoint is broken and the program will not end after it is done reading all of the file.

#### Code

```
i = 0
while i == 0:
  file1 = open('APPMAKE', 'r')
  Lines = file1.readlines()
 
  count = 0
  checkpoint = 0
  ccount = 1
  modeset = 0
  # Strips the newline character
  for line in Lines:
      count += 1
      ccount += 1
      modeset += 1
      if ccount > checkpoint:
        checkpoint += 1
        if modeset > 2:
           modeset == 1
        if modeset == 1:
           elfexecutable = line
        if modeset == 2:
           appname = line
           checkpoint = count + 1
           break
  #writing data
  file1.close()
  file2 = open(appname + ".app", "a")  # append mode
  file2.write(elfexecutable + "\n")
  file2.close()
```

I put this in the APPMAKE file to test:

```
elf.elf
ap.app
elf.elf
ap.app
elf.elf
ap.app
elf.elf
ap.app
```

Oh, and I made a manual to use this Python script. This *might* help you understand it:

```text
APP MAKE INSTRUCTIONS
=====================

First, to generate app, create a APPMAKE file. Next, add repeated code scripts
that are like this:

[elf file to link to]
[app file name]
...

Then, you made a APPMAKE file! To make more configs, list more of the scripts above.
Remember yo replace the things in the []s! Also, you can make a app run more than
1 elf you can make more than 1 configuration for each file. Now, how do you
run a APPMAKE file? Well first go copy & paste (do this sentence if your project is
not a template) the elfexepreferences.sh file into the folder with the
APPMAKE file. (do this even if your project is a template -->) Now, edit the file
you just pasted and edit the part that looks like this:

elfexecute () {
   [function to execute elf] $1
}

Edit the []s depending on what system your apps are running on. (the elf
exepreferences file needs to be in every dir with a APPMAKE file.) And, getting close
to finished, copy and paste the elfexecuter.sh to your programs's main dir if it is
not already there. Then, in the same dir as the elfexecuter.sh file, add a
appexecute file and add a list of the APP files. Now, wanna make an app? To
execute the APPMAKE file, copy and paste appmake.py to the same dir
as the programs if it is not already there. Execute it and your app is
compiled. NOTICE: appexecute conatins names of .app files! Add the extensions!

So, I obeyed with my manual and tested the first few steps and got this to repeat and write a ENDLESS amount of elf.elf to my app file! Can someone please help!
```

My new edit but it still does not work:

```
checkpoint = 0
i = 5
while i == 5:
  file1 = open('APPMAKE', 'r')
  Lines = file1.readlines()
 
  count = 0
  ccount = 0
  modeset = 0
  # Strips the newline character
  for line in Lines:
      count += 1
      ccount += 1
      modeset += 1
      if modeset > 2:
           modeset == 1
      if ccount > checkpoint:
        checkpoint += 1
        if modeset == 1:
           elfexecutable = line
        if modeset == 2:
           appname = line
           checkpoint = count + 1
           break
  #writing data
  file1.close()
  file2 = open(appname + ".app", "a")  # append mode
  file2.write(elfexecutable + "\n")
  file2.close()
```

SOO, above is my newest edit but it *still will not work*! Any help is appreciated. I listened to all the suggestions with the new edit.

Comment: Why do you have the `i = 0` and the while loop? It seems like you have no way to exit it.

Comment: Oh, wait it is meant to repeat forever and it has a "checkpoint" so every read line it contiunes where it left off. Any way to fix that? Sorry for being not too clear.

Comment: Wait, so you *want* it to repeat forever? What's the problem then? Please describe how your output differs from what you want.

Comment: The checkpoint keeps getting reset to 0 at the beginning of each loop, why not just parse all the strings at once and process every two lines? Also `modeset == 1` inside the `if modeset > 2` doesn't set it back to 1.

Comment: Okay thanks everyone for your help!! BUT, I have this issue still, I swapped the code to this: (Look at the post.)

Comment: You still don't set `i` to something else to break out of the loop and I don't think you're actually using the checkpoint properly.

Comment: Okay, I am not modifying the i unless it is done, so it repeats, resumes checkpoint, and writes data, repeat. BUT what I am trying to say is that the checkpoint is broken and the program will not end after it is done reading all of the file.

Comment: Based on your APPMAKE file, what should the correct output be? And should the program *really* keep running forever, even after it saves the output file? If so, why?

Comment: CrazyChucky, you are right. But I do not know how to make the file stop after writing is done. Any help?

Comment: It's hard to advise because I'm still unsure what you want it to do when it's working correctly. You've mentioned both that it should and should not repeat forever. And you haven't specified what the correct output should be with the APPMAKE file shown.

Comment: What does that mean? Please edit the question to show exactly what should be output and where. We'll never be able to help you if you can't explain what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `i` to some value other than zero inside the `while i==0:` loop otherwise it will keep on repeating the whole process indefinitely.

I suspect that you want to exit the main loop when all lines have been processed.  This would happen when there are no lines beyond the check point (which you need to only initialize outside of the main loop).

You can break out of the while-loop, when the for-loop wasn't broken out of by adding an else: statement to the for-loop

```
for line in line:
    ...
    if ccount > checkpoint:
       ...
       if modeset == 2:
          appname = line
          checkpoint = count + 1
          break
else: break      # will break the while if the for-loop wasn't broken
                 # notice that this else: is at the same level as the for-loop
```

Comment: Oh, wait it is meant to repeat forever and it has a "checkpoint" so every read line it contiunes where it left off. Any way to fix that? Sorry for being not too clear.

Comment: @bigDoge This clarification belongs in your question. I edited your question and placed it at the top.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have no exit condition for that loop and the variable is not used again.

It should exit if you remove the `i = 0`, the while loop you have directly below it, and unindent everything by one level. Or you need to create the condition for exiting the loop, like setting `i = 1` somewhere. The break should also exit inner loop, but then it repeats at the beginning again, which might not be what you want.